# Where are files saved in PhoneGap app stored on Android?

Tags: android, cordova

I am using PhoneGap with File plugin. I am able to read & write files to file system and those are persisted correctly. But when I try to locate those files from native file explorer app on tablet or from Windows Explorer (through USB connection), I can't find any traces of these files by browsing to folder that PhoneGap claims to store those (Tablet\Android\data\com.xxx.yyy\files) to nor with search functionality. I do not have any external cards attached to my Android tablet. Any ideas how to find those files?

Comment: You've confirmed that the files are actually persisted across reinstalls? Everything I found about this subject implies it should be in the standard location you mentioned unless you specify that you want to use Environment.getExternalStorage. I'm moving from native android to phonegap in februari so I'm curious.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was implying with persisting. The files are downloaded over HTTP and written to file and are still found with reading after reinstallings of app and restarting the device.

Comment: Ok, since internal storage is supposed to be removed when the app is uninstalled via the device I was just making sure. Maybe it would help to get one of the files as a File and have it display its absolute path?

Comment: Hmm weird, I have an application that takes pictures and writes them to external storage. If I change it to internal storage, they're still stored but they seem to just disappear from the file structure. I don't know how android stores data locally but there aren't even any hidden files from what I can see. Maybe the data gets serialised somewhere? I hope someone with more experience will come by and explain, I'm confused now.

Comment: After you rephrased your question, I have to restate my previous answer: if I just reinstall (without first uninstalling) the app from package, files are persisted. However, if I uninstall the app and then install package again, the files are not persisted (as they probably shouldn't be). And yes, I have checked the hidden files and looked where the app says it saves the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After carefully studying [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) about storage options I spotted that this is the intended behavior of *internal storage* which is used for applications **private** data that shouldn't be possible to read by other applications accessing the file system.

I have all the time thought that the *external* referred to SD cards but instead the external storage is described like this

> Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage"
>   that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media
>   (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage. Files
>   saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified
>   by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a
>   computer.

which seems to be the exact behavior I was looking for. By using the **cordova.file.externalDataDirectory**, I was able to store the files on internal file system (not to SD card) and see them in the file explorer.

I think that the assumption of external storage referring to SD card only isn't totally unreasonable since the [File plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#android-file-system-layout) has */* as a directory for *cordova.file.externalRootDirectory* in file system layout for Android. This must have been the thing that made me think that way.