# Cordova File Download Issue

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to download a file from cordova application. It is giving me message as Download Complete but file is not saved on my device.
Below is the code i am using.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 5 * 1024 * 1024, function(
    fs) {
    alert("Inside" + fs.root.fullPath);
    alert(cordova.file.dataDirectory);
    alert("fs.root" + fs.root.externalRootDirectory);
    var entry = fs.root;
    entry.getDirectory("example", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
    var uri = encodeURI("http://192.168.15.46/test.pdf");
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    var fileURI = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "test21321.pdf";
    ft.download(uri, fileURI, function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("download error" + error.code);
    });
});

function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
    alert("Created dir " + dir.name);
}

function onGetDirectoryFail(error) {
    alert("Error creating directory " + error.code);
}
```

Comment: What if you tried something like this: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/manage-files-in-android-and-ios-using-ionicframework/ ignoring the Ionic Framework part.

Answer (score 0):

How are you deciding whether it is on your device? If you tried to find it through Windows Explorer or native File system explorer, you are facing most probably the same issue as I [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502853/where-are-files-saved-in-phonegap-app-stored-on-android).

Basically you can test that by trying to read the file with File plugin and see if any data is stored there. Also if you have SD card available, try to store on it by changing data directory to be

```
cordova.file.externalDataDirectory
```